# How to create multiple vm nics in a loop using terraform with static ipaddress assigned

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create 2 VM's in Azure using Terraform and each VM requires 4 nics, one in each subnet of the vnet and these nics must be configured with static IP addresses. Is there any way to accomplish this using loops ideally with for_each?

I can do this with 'dynamic' ip address assignment for the ip_configuration block without-issues but need it working with 'static' IP assignment and don't know how to pass the ip address inside the ip_configuration block of the network interface resource block.

I don't know if dynamic block is the right model for this here but I tried to use nested loop with dynamic ip_configuration block without much luck :-(

Here is what I have so far (Snippet for nics for subnet1) and would love to get some help;

```
variable "subnet1IpAddresses" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "The subnet1 IP address to assign to vm nodes."
  default = {
    "1" = "10.10.1.4"  
    "2" = "10.10.1.5"
  }
}

locals {
  vmName = [format("%s%s%s%s%s", var.envPrefix, "-", var.dptPrefix, var.vmPrefix, "01"), format("%s%s%s%s%s", var.envPrefix, "-", var.dptPrefix, var.vmPrefix, "02")]
  subnet1Ip = [var.subnet1IpAddresses[1], var.subnet1IpAddresses[2]] 
}

#create NIC for each NVA and Assign Static IP addresses.
    resource "azurerm_network_interface" "subnet1Nics" {
      for_each                      = toset(local.vmName)
      name                          = "${each.value}subnet1-nic"
      resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
      location                      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
      enable_ip_forwarding          = "true"
      enable_accelerated_networking = "true"
    
      dynamic ip_configuration {
        for_each = local.subnet1Ip
        content {
          name                          = "ipconfig1"
          subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.snet1.id
          private_ip_address            = ip_configuration.value
          private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
          primary                       = "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem with the above code 'as-is' is that it try to create two ip_configurations for the same VM so VM1 will have nic1 with two IP configurations i.e. (10.10.1.4 and 10.10.1.5) but that's not what I need.

Simply put, below is the outcome I desire for this specific example and hoping someone can help with it.

```
VM1's nic1 with IP (10.10.1.4)
VM2's nic1 with IP (10.10.1.5)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to each nic in each subnet? then you need to create 8 NICs. Have you tried to use for loop.

Comment: Correct,  2 nics in each subnet and the example code I have pasted above is for the one subnet, the rest will follow the same logic.  If you have any other way to achieve this please can you share sample code?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu Thanks for the follow-up. I ended up changing quite a bit and used cidrhost to calculate the ip address with count for each subnet nic. I'll try your suggestion and have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for your purpose: 2 VMs, each VM has 4 NICs, 4 subnets in the VNet, each NIC of the VM in a subnet.

main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

variable "nics" {}

variable "vnet_prefix" {}

variable "subnet_prefixes" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "group" {
  name              = "charlesVM"
  location          = "East Asia" 
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name              = "charles-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.group.name
  location          = azurerm_resource_group.group.location
  address_space     = var.vnet_prefix
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnets" {
  count             = length(var.subnet_prefixes)
  name              = "subnet-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefix    = element(var.subnet_prefixes, count.index)
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nics" {
  count             = length(var.nics)
  name              = "nic-${count.index}"
  location          = azurerm_resource_group.group.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.group.name

  ip_configuration {
    name            = "config-${count.index}"
    subnet_id       = element(azurerm_subnet.subnets[*].id, count.index % 4)
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
    private_ip_address = element(var.nics, count.index)
  }
}

locals {
  vm_nics = chunklist(azurerm_network_interface.nics[*].id, 4)
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  count             = 2
  name              = "azurevm-${count.index}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.group.name
  location          = azurerm_resource_group.group.location
  size              = "Standard_DS3_v2"
  admin_username    = "adminuser"
  network_interface_ids = element(local.vm_nics, count.index)

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

terraform.tfvar:

```
nics = [
    "10.0.0.4",
    "10.0.1.4",
    "10.0.2.4",
    "10.0.3.4",
    "10.0.0.5",
    "10.0.1.5",
    "10.0.2.5",
    "10.0.3.5"
]
vnet_prefix = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
subnet_prefixes = [
    "10.0.0.0/24",
    "10.0.1.0/24",
    "10.0.2.0/24",
    "10.0.3.0/24"
]
```

Note that you want to use the static IP address, then you need to calculate them manually to avoid the conflict, and make sure each IP address of the NIC is right in the subnet. And you also need to choose the right VM size that can support 4 NICs for one VM.

Comment: Good, just minor errors: network_interface_ids and address_prefix should be [] list.